# What is the "other miscellaneous information" in the Shared Global Area (oracle database)?

Tags: oracle

I'm studying Oracle database ,and it [says here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c08memor.htm) that the SGA contains these data structures :

```
Database buffer cache
Redo log buffer
Shared pool
Java pool
Large pool (optional)
Data dictionary cache
Other miscellaneous information
```

What is that "    Other miscellaneous information" that is referred to?

thanks

Comment: Probably too many minor details that would cause a burden on the people maintaining the documentation to keep track of. Why do you ask?

Comment: A bit unrelated (because that part didn't change that much) but you shouldn't be studying the documentation of a totally outdated and unsupported Oracle version. Read the manual for 11.x at least (if not 12.x), not 9.x

Answer (score 1):

That "other stuff" is everything else that the database needs to run.

That's a whole lot of things, most of which you'll never need to care about at all. If you're curious to see what the different memory areas are in your system, you can query the `v$sgainfo` view and take a peek. Warning: there's a lot of them (1058 entries on a 12c database I'm connected to right now).

For instance, you'll find a "resize operation history" bucket which should hold the information about dynamic resizing operations (which you can query via `v$sga_resize_ops` view).

Not all of these are documented (mostly because you don't actually care about the majority), but you'll find information about some of them scattered around the web (and occasional bugs related to some of them) if you're curious.

If you're interested about Oracle's memory architecture, the Concepts Guide's [Memory Architecture](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17633/memory.htm#CNCPT1243) sections is quite detailed already, you'll rarely need to mess with things that aren't mentioned there.